# Regexp that matches these strings

Tags: php, regex

I want to filter strings that I have in an csv file, and I'm looking for a correct regexp that matches these strings:

> PLP_LES_HALLES.VOLUME_POMPE
>
> Newyork:Flow(m3/h)

In fact, the string should not contain any characters like : `ç & é @ ! ? “ ' ³ = +` etc.
 I tried this one :
 `([a-zA-Z0-9_:.(\/)]*)` but when I tested it, I figured out that it matches everything. Kindly help me to find the correct one.

Here is  my code to test:

```
   while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $total = count( $line );
        $keys = array('mesure', 'timestamp', 'value');
        $args=array(
          'mesure' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                            'options' => array('regexp' => '([a-zA-Z0-9_:.(\/)]*)')),
          'timestamp' => array( 'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                                'options' => array('min_range' => 20000000000000, 'length' => 14)),
          'value' => FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        $testing = filter_var_array(array_combine($keys, $line), $args);
        var_dump($testing);
    }
```

> EDIT

These strings should not match:

```
PLP_LES_HALLéS.VOLUME_POMPE
PLP_LES_HàLLES.VOLUME_POMPE
Newyork:Flow(m³/h)
```

To sum up, all strings that have any characters from the list `ç & é @ ! ? “ ' ³ = +` etc` should not match

Comment: Your regex matches empty strings

Comment: @Toto How come? should I make many capturing groups? For me, it should match any string that has 0 or more character of each thing inside the brackets

Comment: No, it must be `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\/]*$/'` then. Or shortened: `'/^[\w:.()\/]*$/'`

Comment: @JavaQueen: Wait ... you want to match what there is INSIDE the parenthesis?

Comment: @Toto I want to allow having the characters  / and  ( and ) literally

Comment: @JavaQueen:This is not my question. What do you want to match?

Comment: @Toto I need to match the parenthesis literally

Comment: @JavaQueen; Why don't you just add anchors? `'regexp' => '(^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.(\/)]*$)'`? Or using `/` as regex delimiter: `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.(\/)]*$/'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your first comment is very helpful. Kindly add an answer. the regexp worked perfectly

Comment: @JavaQueen:Yes, I understand. But from your string,do you want to match the whole string or only what there is inside the parenthesis? Please give some test cases, some strings that should match and some that shouldn't, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not match the whole string, and you are using ambiguous regex delimiter, it is recommended to use more common symbols as regex delimiters.

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\/]*$/'
 ^^                   ^^
```

The `^` will match the start of the string, and `$` will match its end, requiring a whole string match.

Also, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be written as `\w`, use it to shorten the pattern (this is not recommended only if you do not want to match Unicode strings):

```
'/^[\w:.()\/]*$/'
```